# kendo grid filter works with "contains" but not equality

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can't get the equality filter ("is equal to" or "is not equal to") to work on the "Request Status" column in a kendo grid.  I can use it on other columns in the grid, such as Buyer.

But the "contains" filter works on the "Request Status" column.  Why doesn't equals work?

Example:  Contains "Rejected" filters correctly.  Equal to "Rejected" does not.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="k-content">
    <table id="grid" style="display:none;">
        <colgroup>
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
        </colgroup>
        <thead style="font-size:80%;">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Request Status</th> 
                <th>Vendor Rep</th>
                <th>Buyer</th>
                <th>UPC</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Create Date</th>
                <th>Update Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var itemRequest in this.Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@itemRequest.Id</td>
                    <td>@(itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Draft ? "Draft" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.MerchandisingReview ? "Merchandising" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.SpacePlanningReview ? "Space Planning" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.DataIntegrityReview ||
                                itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.DataIntegrityFinalReview ? "Data Integrity" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.VendorRepReview ? "Vendor Rep" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Approved ? "Approved" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Rejected ? "Rejected" : ""
                            )))))))
                     </td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.GetAuthor().FirstName @itemRequest.GetAuthor().LastName</td>
                    <td>@(itemRequest.GetBuyer() != null ? @String.Format("{0}", itemRequest.GetBuyer().Name) : "")</td>                    
                    <td>@itemRequest.Upc</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.BrandCode</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.Description</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.CreateDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@(itemRequest.LastUpdateDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)itemRequest.LastUpdateDate).ToShortDateString() : "")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/kendo/js/kendo.web.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                filterable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                Id: { type: "number" },
                                //2014-03-27: Issue #69
                                ItemRequestStatusId: { type: "string" },
                                VendorRep: { type: "string" },
                                Buyer: { type: "string" },
                                Upc: { type: "number" },
                                Brand: { type: "string" },
                                Description: { type: "string" },
                                CreateDate: { type: "date" },
                                UpdateDate: { type: "date" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "Id", template: "<a href=\"/items/itemrequest/display/#: Id #\">#: Id # </a>" },
                    { field: "ItemRequestStatusId" },
                    { field: "VendorRep" },
                    { field: "Buyer" },
                    { field: "Upc" },
                    { field: "Brand" },
                    { field: "Description" },
                    { field: "CreateDate", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
                    { field: "UpdateDate", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" }
                ]
            });

            $("#grid").css("display", "table");

            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var hide = $('#hide_Status').val()
            if(hide)
            {
                grid.hideColumn(1);
            }

            var tacos = 0;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm confused. You don't have `Request Status` as one of your columns in the grid initialization?  I only see `ItemRequestStatusId`

Comment: @RickS I want the column heading to display as "Request Status" but it refers to the data in the ItemRequestStatusId field.  Is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, it works to assign the ItemRequestStatusId to a variable, and then use that variable in the cell.

**Change to HTML:**

```
 @foreach (var itemRequest in this.Model)
            {
                string status = (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Draft ? "Draft" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.MerchandisingReview ? "Merchandising" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.SpacePlanningReview ? "Space Planning" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.DataIntegrityReview ||
                                itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.DataIntegrityFinalReview ? "Data Integrity" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.VendorRepReview ? "Vendor Rep" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Approved ? "Approved" :
                            (itemRequest.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.Rejected ? "Rejected" : ""
                            )))))));
                <tr>
                    <td>@itemRequest.Id</td>
                    <td>@status</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.GetAuthor().FirstName @itemRequest.GetAuthor().LastName</td>
                    <td>@(itemRequest.GetBuyer() != null ? @String.Format("{0}", itemRequest.GetBuyer().Name) : "")</td>                    
                    <td>@itemRequest.Upc</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.BrandCode</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.Description</td>
                    <td>@itemRequest.CreateDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@(itemRequest.LastUpdateDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)itemRequest.LastUpdateDate).ToShortDateString() : "")</td>
                </tr>
            }
```